# Did the same dog play Einstein in Back to the Future I and II?

Tags: character, casting, back-to-the-future, back-to-the-future-part-2

The question is self explanatory:  did the same dog play Einstein in the first two Back to the Future movies?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The BTTF Blog article on [Einstein](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Einstein) indicates that the dog in the first film ([Tiger](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Tiger)) was replaced by a second dog ([Freddie](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Freddie)) for the second two installments:

> In Back to the Future, Einstein was portrayed by a dog named Tiger, trained by animal trainer Richard Calkins. Twenty-eight dog years later, when Parts II and III of the trilogy were being filmed, animal trainer Matilda de Cagny provided another canine actor called Freddie, to portray Einstein (as Tiger was too old to continue the role). Freddie, alongside Christopher Lloyd, Thomas F. Wilson, and Darlene Vogel, also appeared in the film for Back to the Future: The Ride.

However, further investigation (prompted by [Kristi Cos's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/46339/7812) below) and [this article](http://articles.latimes.com/1986-11-13/news/vw-25194_1_lassie-vii) from the LA Times in 1986 strongly suggest that the original Einstein was played by *two different dogs*; Tiger, trained by Richard Calkins and another dog named O.J., trained by [Bob Weatherwax](http://www.weatherwaxtraineddogs.com/).

[image]

Notably, the owners for both of the dogs *share* a film credit as ['Animal Handlers'](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088763/fullcredits/)

Comment: I'm glad Tiger wasn't already dead by the time the sequels were made.  Thanks, Richard.

Comment: Ah, Tiger. What a performer. His head twist in BTTF (pictured above) is widely recognized as one of the greatest moments in animal performance history. Per the unauthorized bio, Tiger never got over being replaced by Freddie, and eventually died alcoholic and broke. Meanwhile, rumor is Freddie has a new reality show in development with Bravo...

Answer (score 1):

No, the dog in the original Back to the Future was named O.J. I did a Tree Top apple juice commercial with him when I was 13.

Comment: Can you support this with any proof that the dog you did the commercial with is the same dog? This clearly disagrees with the information in the other answer but has no supporting evidence.

Comment: Interesting. I found this on the [Bob Weatherwax dog training website](http://www.weatherwaxtraineddogs.com/)- "*Bob's filmography includes: ... Back to the Future - ...  Lassie VII & **O.J. (Einstein from " Back to the Future"**)"

Comment: And this from the [LA Times](http://articles.latimes.com/1986-11-13/news/vw-25194_1_lassie-vii) - *"After all, among them are O.J., a sheep dog who played Einstein in the movie "Back to the Future" and who is now in Canada portraying an Old Yeller-type in The TV movie "Stone Fox," and Corky, the Maltese who deserted Nick Nolte in the film "Down and Out in Beverly Hills.""*

Comment: @Richards It's nice that you found that and it sure makes your answer better. But it doesn't really make *this* answer much better, at least not until edited into it in some way. And I'm sure as a connoisseur of well-sourced answers you're aware of that.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - That's true, but I still felt it deserves an upvote. Kristi may not have provided any evidence but this all rings true. I suspect this may be the advert in question... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oL4_2kbhMgM